# How to split bytes of number into an Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, binary

I want to split a js number into the smallest uint8array.

For example :

```
65 535 = Uint8Array<[255,255]> (0b1111111111111111 = [0b11111111, 0b11111111])
12 356 = Uint8Array<[48,68]> (0b0011000001000100 = [0b00110000, 0b01000100])
1 142 =  Uint8Array<[4,118]> (0b0011000001000100 = [0b00000100, 0b01110110])
400 = Uint8Array<[1,144]> (0b0000000110010000 = [0b00000001, 0b10010000])
256 = Uint8Array<[1,0]> (0b0000000100000000 = [0b00000001, 0b00000000])
64 =  Uint8Array<[64]> (0b0000000001000000 = [0b01000000])
-1 = Uint8Array<[]> I don't want to support negative number
```

I have try to edited bytes by bytes like that :

```js
const buffer : Uint8Array = new Uint8Array([0,0])
buffer[bytePos] &= ~(1<<bitToEdit); //to set at 0
buffer[bytePos] |= (1 <<bitToEdit) //to set at 1
```

the bytes edit work but I don't know how to read bytes from the number and how to push bytes of number into this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), modulus (`%`) and [Uint8Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from).

For negative numbers and for `0`, this implementation returns an empty Uint8Array (with zero elements).  This implementation outputs in Big Endian (as your example shows) by reversing the byte array.

```js
function toByteArray(n) {
  let b = BigInt(n);
  let result = [];
  while (b > 0n) {
    result.push(Number(b % 0x100n));
    b /= 0x100n;
  }
  return Uint8Array.from(result.reverse());
}

console.log(toByteArray(
  0x01_00_00_00_00_00_00_00_03n
)) // Uint8Array(9) [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3 ]
```

Comment: I have tried the function but that doesn't work in typescript(I don't have precise that ^^') because /= can"t apply to big int. And I'm not sure what means this syntax: 0x100n ?

Comment: `0x100n` is a big integer literal `0x100`  `0x` is the hexadecimal prefix.  I could have written `256n` instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have fixe my typescript error and now it works thanks ^^.
If someone interested here is the typescript function : `public static toByteArray(data : number) : Uint8Array{
        let b = BigInt(data);
        let result = [];
        while (b > 0) {
            result.push(Number(b % BigInt(256)));
            b /= BigInt(256);
        }
        return Uint8Array.from(result.reverse());
    }`